# Configure charles proxy to intercept traffic on Android N device

Tags: networking, charles-proxy, android-7.0-nougat

With Android-N OS, does anyone know the steps to be followed to configure charles proxy to intercept Android N traffic for debugging purposes?

Comment: I have issues as well since Android N. It was working before. Updating charles did not help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an SSL certificate, and then add this to both charles and your app.

There's some instructions on how to create the certificate and get charles to use it here:
http://codeblog.shape.dk/blog/2014/01/06/custom-ssl-certificate-with-charles-web-proxy/

(I'd read the entire blog post, but the pertinent bit is in the section "Custom SSL certificate")

Then, depending upon your requirements, you will need to get your app (or a flavour thereof) to use that certificate by adding a network_security_config.xml file with configuration options to suit your needs. This topic is described in the following links:

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html

https://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html

Comment: I have tried embedding the charles CA in the debug build of the app as outlined here:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#TrustingDebugCa

And unfortunately it does not seem to work. If the problem was the certificate, we would still see encrypted traffic in Charles. For me, I don't see any traffic at all which implies the issue is with proxying.

Comment: I've successfully used the mechanism above to read N traffic with charles. Without additional info regarding your specific situation I can't offer any insight sorry.